# Is there an SSH client which duplicates commands to multiple terminals?

Tags: ssh, administration

I'd like to control several ssh connections from one terminal. For example, I would type `ifconfig` in the main terminal and all the other ssh connections would run `ifconfig`. That's what offered PuttyCM on Windows [for example](http://vmwise.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/puttycm2.jpg).

This may be a very simple question but I did not manage to find such a ssh connection manager. I would not be too hard to code but it surely already exists. Could you give some hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Cluster SSH

Cluster SSH is used to start multiple SSH connections in separate terminal windows, with a common input box. You type in the input box and the keystrokes are sent to all the connected terminals.

```
sudo apt-get install clusterssh
```

Then run [`cssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cssh.1p):

```
cssh host1 host2 ...
```

#### Use a terminal emulator with broadcasting

Terminator, for example, is a terminal emulator in which you can broadcast keystrokes to a group of terminals.:

[image]
[image]

---

Depending on how many connections you make, Cluster SSH might be the better option. However, it uses `xterm` for the terminal emulator, which may not be what you are used to. It is, however, much more easy to get started with a number of connections using `cssh`, than to create a lot of splits and group them in Terminator. For example, this is what `cssh osl-{01..95}` gets me:

[image]

The terminal windows were are all resized and tiled nicely. The gaps are for windows that were closed because the connection failed.

Answer (score 5):

There are many options to achieve what you want. My favorite is `pssh` (Parallel SSH). It can run commands parallely on multiple hosts and have variety of options.

You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install pssh
```

`pssh` has some added advantages like it will be installed with `parallel-scp`, `parallel-rsync` binaries to do as their names suggest.

Here is an example to run `whoami` command as user `foobar` on two hosts using `pssh`:

```
parallel-ssh -iAH "host_1 host_2" -l foobar "whoami"
```

Check `man pssh` or [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/parallel-ssh.1.html) to get more idea.