# How can I install software on my client using my Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, client

As I have been told, there Is no 'official' method to replace MS Server completely, but yet for each usage case, requires another set of software, I will rephrase this on what I want know.

I am looking for a way to install packages on my Ubuntu client from my Ubuntu Server!

To give you an image on what I want, is this, select my client and install the software I want to install on it, from my server!

[image: Ninite Pro: The easiest way to manage software.]

---

Additional Information:

- Ubuntu Desktop (laptop)

  - Ubuntu Unity, Trusty Tahr, 14.04.3
- Ubuntu Server (laptop)

  - Ubuntu Mate, Trusty Tahr, 14.04.3

Both are connected to the internet via WiFi.

Comment: Software is installed a different way in Ubuntu. You can install software any Ubuntu comp by logging there through ssh. It is installed from repositories. You can setup a local mirror, etc.

Comment: Use configuration management tools like Landscape, Puppet, Chef, etc.

Comment: I guess you're looking for a GUI program? Otherwise how about simply `ssh`?

Comment: @Kos preferably a GUI, but, if ssh is my only option, then ssh I will use.

Comment: @kos preferably a GUI, but, if ssh is my only option, then ssh I will use

Answer (score 5):

Since as per your comment a CLI solution is ok, I'll post a CLI solution which you may use if you don't find a GUI equivalent;

Running `ssh` on the local host (in this case on the Ubuntu Server installation) you can get an `ssh` shell running on the remote host (in this case on the Ubuntu Desktop installation) which you can use to install the software via the command-line as you would on the local host (e.g. by compiling / installing or by running `apt-get`);

First, install the `ssh` server on the remote host:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then you can run an `ssh` shell on the remote host by running the `ssh` client on the local host:

```
ssh user@host
```

Where `user` is the user you want to login as on the remote host and where `host` is the remote host's name / IP address.

The first time you'll be prompted with a message like this one:

```
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Typing `yes` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> you'll be prompted for your password:

```
user@localhost's password:
```

Typing your password and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> you'll be prompted with a message like this one:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-15-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

240 packages can be updated.
139 updates are security updates.


The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.
```

Typing `exit` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will end the `ssh` session:

```
user@user-X550CL ~ % exit
Connection to localhost closed.
```

While in an `ssh` session as a certain user you can execute any command the user can run on the remote host.

Installing software on the remote host from the local host using `ssh` + `apt-get` can be simplified e.g. by adding an user-defined function in your local host's `~/.bashrc` (remember to run `source ~/.bashrc` afterwards):

```bsh
function apt-get_install_remote_host {
    ssh -t user@host sudo apt-get install $@
    exit 0
}
```

And by calling the function:

```
apt-get_install_remote_host package1 package2 package3
```

**Further Reading**:

- [Is there an SSH client which duplicates commands to multiple terminals?](https://askubuntu.com/q/612964/158442)
- [How to setup passwordless SSH access for root user](https://askubuntu.com/q/115151/380067)

Comment: Also look into [simultaneously SSHing to multiple systems](http://askubuntu.com/q/612964/158442), [passwordless SSH to root](http://askubuntu.com/a/115323/158442) (with a password-protected private key).

Comment: I installed the `openssh-server` package on my client, but my server can't seem to connect to it?

Comment: Ensure port 22 is open on both systems and any required port forwarding is done.

Comment: @blade19899 I see that you're connecting to the remote machine through a router: you should allow inbound connections on port 22 on the remote host in your router's configuration (as well as inbound connections on port 22 on the remote machine in the remote machine's firewall's configuration if you're using one)

Comment: On my client I can see - in the `gufw`, listening report - `sshd` using protocol `TCP6`, Port `22`, adres `*` On my server `gufw` doesn't show a ssh process?

Comment: @blade19899 If you didn't setup a firewall on your client setting up the router is enough, it should be pretty straightforward; here's an example on my router: http://i.imgur.com/9lry08m.png. Text is in italian, apologizes, however the first drop-down menu is to select the port, in this case TCP:22  *and* UDP:22 (you need to open both), the second drop-down menu is to select the action to perform (in this case "Allow always") and the IP address entered below is the local IP address for which the ports should be opened.

Comment: @blade19899 No because on the server you don't need an `ssh` server to be running, you just need the client to be installed, in order to use it connect to the server running on the remote host

Answer (score 1):

An extension to @kos's answer. I found a GUI client for SHH, for Linux. [Putty, a free telnet/ssh client](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). It resides in the Ubuntu Trusty Tahr repository:

I looks pretty straight forward, as seen here on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Putty has an advantage, if you don't want to learn `ssh` command syntax (which is pretty simple for the basic stuff and otherwise a look into the manual away) or how to store per-domain settings in the configuration file. Ultimately `ssh` and its configuration are more powerful.